# Why Don't I have 'this' context inside of a .then() in my Ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, this

I'm fairly new to Ember.

This is the code for my component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  profiles: Ember.inject.service(),
  tagName: 'td',
  classNames: ['grey'],
  classNameBindings: ['unreadMessages'],
  unreadMessages: null,

onInit: function() {
    const id = this.get('conversation.id');
    return this.get('profiles').getMessages(id)
      .then(function(bool) {
        this.set('unreadMessage', bool);
      });
  }.on('init')
});
```

This throws:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined
```

So I can gather that I don't have the `this` context that I need to call `this.set` inside of the `.then()`

I need to assign the result of `return this.get('profiles').getMessages(id)` to the `unreadMessages` property in my component. So that I can use it for the `classNameBinding`.

Here is the method I'm calling from the service

```
  getMessages(id){
    return this.get('ajax').request('/messages?id=' + id)
    .then((obj) => {
      const unreadMessages = obj.messages.filter((e) => e.read === false);

      if (unreadMessages === []) {
         return false;
      } else {
         return true;
      }
    });
  }
```

I've only been able to access the boolean value that getMessages returns inside of its `.then()` and I am not able to call `this.set()` inside of the `.then()`  I'm looking for a work around. I think I'm close and am struggling to due to my lack of experience with Ember.

`getMessages` makes a `'GET'` request to my back end and filters through the messages to check if there are any that are unread and then returns true or false. The purpose of the `classNameBinding` is to notify the user of whether they have any unread messages for that thread. This is a very simple email style messaging app that I am building for practice.

Thanks!

Comment: It's a normal js tweak, the scope is changed and you are not using arrow functions :)

Comment: *this* is not "context". It's a parameter of an execution context that is set by the call, use of bind or adopted from the containing execution context in arrow functions.

Comment: Instead of `on('init')`, I would encourage you to write it inside `init` method itself, that's good practice.

Comment: You should also read [*How to access the correct `this` context inside a callback?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
onInit: function() {
    const id = this.get('conversation.id');
    return this.get('profiles').getMessages(id)
      .then(function(bool) {
        this.set('unreadMessage', bool);
      });
  }.on('init')
});
```

to

```
onInit: function() {
    const id = this.get('conversation.id');
    return this.get('profiles').getMessages(id)
      .then((bool) => {
        this.set('unreadMessage', bool);
      });
  }.on('init')
});
```

The thing here is, the scope changes when you write `function(){}` inside then and `this` won't refer to the component this.
That's why in ES6 the concept of lexical `this` was introduced. This will retain the `this`. So use Arrow function instead and it'll work smoothly..

Comment: Good answer.  Another trick I used (pre Babel) is to assign `this` to a variable (I prefer to name it `self`), then use `self` instead of `this`.  Whenever you see "function" in JS, always remember "THIS is not what you might expect...".